# PHP Function Argument Default Value

Tags: php, function

Hey all.
I have a **processForm** function and a **displayForm** function. If there are missing form fields the **processForm** function returns an array of missing fields. This is all fine and dandy until I try to include this array into the **displayForm** function. **Here's the problem:**

If I don't do this:

```
displayForm($missingFields=array());
```

then my **validateField** function throws a warning that it is expecting the parameter to be an array. **However,** this overwrites the array returned by the **processForm** function.

I hope I'm clear. Thanks for any help.

Full Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] = "login")
{
    $messages = processForm();
}
```

> processForm()

```
if($errorMessages)
{
     return array("errors" => $errorMessages, "missing" => $missingFields);
}
else 
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

form.php

```
(!isLoggedIn())? displayForm($messages['errors']=array(),$messages['missing']=array()) : null;
```

These are the sections of the code I'm having trouble with.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please show us how you're using that code, the problem is *not* very clear at the moment.

Comment: OK I'll edit the above...few minutes...

Comment: I could be jumping the gun here by suggesting posting on codereview.stackexchange.com.  It sounds like your trouble may be buried too deep in your code for a regular SO question.  Otherwise, you'll have to be _way_ more specific in showing the problem lines.

Comment: @Tablekin: also, just a suggestion for posting code examples on SO: you can write out all the code you want in a text editer such as Notepad++, select all text, hit tab once to insert proper indenting, then copy/paste into here so everything is automatically properly formatted.

Comment: @Phil Brown: yes apparently I was jumping the gun.

Comment: @Tableking: no problem.  The formatting of SO does take some getting used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set default argument values in the call, you set them in the signature, for example

```
function displayForm($arg1 = array()) {
    ...
}
```

---

When you write

> displayForm($messages['errors']=array())

this is actually doing something like this

```
$messages['error'] = array(); // set $messages['error'] to an empty array
displayForm($messages['error']); // pass an empty array to displayForm
```

This is because in PHP, the return value from an assignment is the value assigned.

Comment: Thanks much. That was the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this:

```
displayForm($messages['errors']=array(),$messages['missing']=array())
```

When you writing **"$messages['errors']=array()"**, this is setting **$messeges** to blank array. So the parameter is blank. You can just write:

```
displayForm($messages['errors'],$messages['missing'])
```